# Adding index for date field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, composite-index

We are using soft delete in our project. So by default, each query will produce with where condition as `"deleted_at is NULL"` and when using some other scopes(only_deleted) query may be `"deleted_at is NOT NULL"`. In this case, is it necessary to add composite index with deleted_at column.

Say I have a model User and user belongs to a specific project and I am trying to add composite index with [project_id, id]. Do I have to include deleted_at as well in this case?

Comment: you can set a `default_scope` on the model to `"deleted_at is NULL"`, and in the other model, you can choose to select `unscoped` entries, which will include all. Also, do you really need an index on that field?

Comment: Yes of course, adding indexes will make all your queries faster. It's better to add indexes for every condition in your query ( index :user_id, :project_id, :deleted_at )